# Can you chain ng-class conditions?

Tags: html, angularjs

So a normal ng-class condition would look something like this

```
ng-class="(condition1) ? 'Cond1true': 'Cond1NotTrue'"
```

Is it however possible to follow the false result with another condition?

Something like

```
ng-class="(condition1) ? 'Cond1true': (condition2) ? 'Cond1False2True': 'Cond1False2False'
```

I tried it the way above but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be your condition2 not returning correct value otherwise your code should work.
Example working code :

controller

```
$scope.condition = 'y';
$scope.condition2 = 'x';
```

css

```
.classOne{
    color: red;
}
.classTwo{
    color: blue;
}
```

html

```
<div ng-class="(condition == 'x') ? 'classOne': (condition2 == 'x')?'classTwo':'classThree'">ok</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this object notation concept in [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

```
[ngClass]="{'Cond1true':condition1, 'Cond1False2True': condition2, 'Cond1False2False':!condition2}"
```